# Sequence-like on tuples

Tags: haskell, tuples, haskell-lens

Consider a code using a [tuple](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple-0.3.0.2/docs/Data-Tuple-Sequence.html#t:SequenceT):

```hs
import Data.Tuple.All  -- tuple library
import Control.Lens

..............

f2 :: (SequenceT a1 b, Each s a1 a2 b2) => s -> (a2 -> b2) -> b
f2 tpl f = sequenceT $ tpl & each %~ f
```

Example of the usage:

```hs
> f x = print x >> pure x
> f2 (1,2,3,4) f
1
2
3
4
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

which means that as I have a `map` and `sequence` on lists, now I have `f2` on tuples. But `f2` depends on the [tuple](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple-0.3.0.2/docs/Data-Tuple-Sequence.html#t:SequenceT).

How can I write the same `f2` using just lens? Without `sequenceT`. Is it possible?

*PS. Maybe you know another similarly simple solutions?*

Comment: Why do you want to do this without depending on `tuple`? It seems the right tool for the job, if any. And it's a much lighter dependency than `lens`. What you _should_ consider is whether you really want to traverse over tuples in the first place; this looks more like a job for fixed-length lists (aka vectors).

Comment: @leftaroundabout just theoretical reasons, I want to know is it possible to do it just with lens (cos I used to think about them as about very powerful "tool")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You indeed don't need the package *tuple*, only *lens*, since `f2` is actually just `flip each`.

```
import Control.Lens

f2 :: (Each s t a b, Applicative f) => s -> (a -> f b) -> f t
f2 = flip each

main = do
  xs <- f2 (1,2,3) (\x -> print x >> pure (x :: Int))
  print xs

{- Output:
1
2
3
(1,2,3)
-}
```